# Homology of a finite graph follows from Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Tags: algebraic-topology

## Problem

(Fulton's *Algebraic Topology: A First Course*, **Exercise 10.15**) If $X$ is a finite graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges, and $X$ has $k$ connected components, show that $H_1X$ is a free abelian group with $e-v+k$ generators.

## Thoughts

First, WLOG, we could assume that $k=1$, i.e. $X$ is connected, and choose a spanning tree $T$ of $X$. Obviously, $T$ is contractible, therefore $H_0T=\mathbb Z$ and $H_1T=0$, and we're done when $e=v-1$. Now induction on $e$. Choose an edge $K$ of $X$ with the midpoint $p$. Let $U=X\setminus\{p\}$, and $V=\operatorname{Int}K$, the interior of $K$. The Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $U,V$ should be
\begin{align*}
0&\to H_1(U\cap V)\to H_1(U)\oplus H_1(V)\to H_1(U\cup V)\\
&\to H_0(U\cap V)\to H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)\to H_0(U\cup V)\to0
\end{align*}
and we can (by induction) obtain that
\begin{align*}
&H_1(U\cap V)=0,H_0(U\cap V)\cong\mathbb Z^{\oplus 2}\\
&H_1(U)\cong H_1(X\setminus V)\cong\mathbb Z^{\oplus(e-v)},H_1(V)=0\\
&H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)\cong\mathbb Z^{\oplus 2},H_0(U\cup V)=\mathbb Z
\end{align*}
However, I don't know how to make use of these information.

Any idea? Thanks!

Postscript: I don't know whether reduced homology could be used to conclude, but I prefer a proof without it since it's subsequently introduced in **Problem 10.17**.

Comment: You haven't computed $H_1(U)$ and $H_1(V)$ yet.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. I've edited to include these.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain what you mean in the first part when you say "and we are done when $k=v-1$"?. And I am failing to see how we generalize this when we have $k$ connected components. Thanks

Comment: @Cedric That was a typo. It should have been $e=v-1$ (with $k=1$), which is equivalent to the graph being a tree. Thanks for the question.

Comment: No problem, it took me a while but eventually I understood it was typo haha. I would like to ask you some related question just in case. Do you how we can prove that the complement of the embedding of a graph in the plane has $e-v+k+1$ connected components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Here's a proof without reduced homology (which, by the way, makes the problem much simpler). To sum up what you've written (as far as I can tell it's correct), you're left with:

$$0 \to \underbrace{H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V)}_{\Z^{e-v}} \to H_1(X) \to \underbrace{H_0(U \cap V)}_{\Z^2} \xrightarrow{g} \underbrace{H_0(U) \oplus H_0(V)}_{\Z^2} \xrightarrow{f} \underbrace{H_0(X)}_{\Z} \to 0$$

$f$ sends $(a,b)$ to $a-b$ (because this is the MV sequence). The map $g$ sends both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ (easy examination). Finally you're left with an exact sequence:

$$0 \to \Z^{e-v} \to H_1(X) \to \Z \to 0$$
where the last $\Z$ is generated by $(1,-1)$ in $H_0(U \cap V) \simeq \Z^2$. By general facts about exact sequences (namely, $\Z$ is projective because it is free), you get $H_1(X) \simeq \Z^{e-v} \oplus \Z$.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more how you obtained the last isomorphism?

Comment: @Cedric Let $P=\mathbb Z$. Every surjective morphism $p\colon M\to P$ of abelian groups admits a section $s\colon P\to M$ (i.e. $s$ is a morphism of abelian groups and $p\circ s=\operatorname{id}$). Then it is direct to show that $(\ker p)\oplus P\to M,(x,y)\mapsto x+s(y)$ is an isomorphism. The last comment about projectivity is that this holds for all $P$ being projective $\mathbb Z$-modules, not just for $P=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

We consider the case with only one connected component, like what you've said. We choose the spanning tree $T$ and done with $e=v-1$. We use Mayer-Vietoris in reduced homology, that is,
\begin{align*}
0&\to H_1(U\cap V)\to H_1(U)\oplus H_1(V)\to H_1(X)\\
&\to \tilde{H}_0(U\cap V)\to \tilde{H}_0(U)\oplus \tilde{H}_0(V)\to \tilde{H}_0(X)\to0
\end{align*}
Since $X,U,V$ are connected, thus $0$, but $U\cap V$ has two connected component, thus $\tilde{H}_0(U\cap V)=\mathbb{Z}$. So we have 
$$0\to H_1(U) \to H_1(X)\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
as a short exact sequence. Then we use the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864292/generators-of-groups-from-exact-sequence) to prove induction hypothesis.